# How to make multiple elements' height resize identically as word wrapping occurs from resizing the viewport?

Tags: html, css

I have 2 elements with varying amounts of text in them. When the viewport is wide enough, their heights are identical. When resized, each element extends their height by varying rates from one another due to the word wrapping to keep it in the box.

All the solutions I've found tend to fix this by using the `min-height` attribute by extending both boxes to the maximum height as if they were already squished. But this solution leaves a lot of white space in the lower content element when the viewport is already wide enough.

I'd like to make 2 elements 'related' to notice if one div height has extended, then make sure the other element extends as well, even if it's not necessary for that low content element.

My code that unfortunately allows the boxes to extend varying heights due to word wrapping:

```
<div style="border: 5px solid;">`
  <h1>Not much here to need to resize</h1>
</div>

<div style="border: 5px solid;">
  <h1>There are a lot of words to word wrap and thus resize my box element much more</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: can you use javascript ?

Comment: I'd prefer against using javascript if it's not necessary. But if that's the only way, then I'll do it. I wonder if there are any other better 'hacks' besides using the `min-height` attribute, since that works well but only if the elements have a fairly similar amount of content in them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On elements at the same row, you can use CSS flex-box. The cross lines solution is Javascript:

This function called on body load/resize picks the second div's height and applies on the first div.

```js
document.body.onload = dsiz();
window.addEventListener('resize', dsiz);  

function dsiz() {
var hhh = document.getElementById("second").offsetHeight;
document.getElementById("first").style.height = hhh + 'px';
}
```

```html
<div id=first style="border: 5px solid;">`
  <h1>Not much here to need to resize</h1>
</div>

<div id=second style="border: 5px solid;">
  <h1>There are a lot of words to word wrap and thus resize my box element much more</h1>
</div>
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2yofxea8/)

Comment: This solution is exactly the concept I'm looking for. However, I notice at certain narrow viewports the elements will resize independently, but for the most part they do resize in tandem. Is there a way to fix this occasional anomaly or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: Actually I notice in the Edge browser, they always resize identically, however in Chrome there are a few spots where there's a "lag" between both of them resizing. It may just be a browser issue?

Comment: I havent noticed this independent resize behavior at narrow viewports yet, I'll do more tests to check;

Comment: I made some tests... It doesn't happens on my Chrome 49; neighter on my firefox 45;

Comment: Tested with success on Opera aswell;

Comment: I retested myself and can't get that "lag" issue to happen anymore myself in either browser. Works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: His solution is better, here is what I was talking about when side by side: https://jsfiddle.net/p005z94b/